# Very strange exception ,IndexOutOfBoundsException in 4.4 but working well in 5.0 : Android

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, indexoutofboundsexception, android-4.4-kitkat, onresume

in detail,

i have **class A** and in that class i have

```
  public static ArrayList<String> video_title = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and ***all the values of video_title are filled in class A***

than i am going to **class B from class A** and accessing ArrayList as A.video_title.get(index).. ok thats working fine as excepted..

Now real problem occurs,
I am opening Android default web view from link of class B and when i come back to my Activity (obviously when i press back from web view it opens my last activity class B), it gives `IndexOutOfBoundsException` and says that `Invalid index 2, size is 0.`

More strange is that, it gives error in `Android 4.4.4` but working fine in

```
Android 5.0.2
```

my code of both class as below (i am sharing only necessary code because my app have some sensitive code ),

Class A:

```
public class A extends Activity{

public static ArrayList<String> video_title = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_of_video);


    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
    {


        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            video_title.clear();

        };

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try
            {
                JSONObject obj = Handle_json.HTTPGet(“here is my url from data is come“);

                nextPageToken = obj.getString("nextPageToken");

                JSONArray items = obj.getJSONArray("items");

                for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++)
                {

                    JSONObject jobj = items.getJSONObject(i);

                    video_title.add("" + omg.getString("title"));

                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            pDialog.dismiss();

        };

    }.execute();

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.in2, R.drawable.out2);
  }
 }
```

Class B:

```
public class B extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity implements OnFullscreenListener{

TextView video_detail_title, video_detail_title2, video_detail_views,
    like_count, dislike_count, video_detail_desc;
ImageView video_detail_iv;

ProgressBar video_detail_pb;

int position = 0;

RelativeLayout main_content;

private View videoBox;
private View closeButton;
YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_detail);

    final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    position = bundle.getInt("position");

    main_content = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);

    videoBox = findViewById(R.id.video_box);
    closeButton = findViewById(R.id.close_button);
    videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            onClickClose();
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.video_detail_iv).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (videoBox.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
            {
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
                {
                    // Initially translate off the screen so that it can be animated in from below.
                    videoBox.setTranslationY(videoBox.getHeight());
                }
                videoBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            // If the fragment is off the screen, we animate it in.
            if (videoBox.getTranslationY() > 0)
            {
                videoBox.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(300);
            }

        }
    });


    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    youTubeView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

    video_detail_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.video_detail_title);
    video_detail_title.setText("" + A.video_title.get(position));


}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.in2, R.drawable.out2);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer arg1, boolean arg2)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!arg2)
    {
        arg1.cueVideo(Show_List_Of_Video.video_id.get(position));
    }
}

@Override
protected Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
}

private boolean isFullscreen;

@Override
public void onFullscreen(boolean arg0)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.isFullscreen = arg0;

    closeButton.setVisibility(isFullscreen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    if (isFullscreen)
    {
        videoBox.setTranslationY(0);

    }

}

public void onClickClose()
{
    ViewPropertyAnimator animator = videoBox.animate().translationYBy(videoBox.getHeight()).setDuration(300);
    runOnAnimationEnd(animator, new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

@TargetApi(16)
private void runOnAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator animator, final Runnable runnable)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
    {
        animator.withEndAction(runnable);
    }
    else
    {
        animator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                runnable.run();
            }
        });
    }
  }

 }
```

***Added After :***

i found that all variable of all activity is cleared when i back to the activity B. why this is happening? even i declare variable as a static. what is going wrong?

Comment: try to compile with latest JDK 1.7 or 1.8

Comment: if thats problem of JDK than it should also gives error in 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

When you `Pause` your activity android kitkat 4.4.4 free memory by removing your arraylist. You can declare a static arraylist to avoid this problem. or on `onPause` save arraylist in preferences and load back on `onResume`.

Comment: Have you tried to create list inside of `onCreate`? `video_title = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: i tried just a moment ago after your comment, but it not works !